# Как правильно в данном случае: «тем» или «для тех»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, управление

Как правильно: *сделать информацию доступной тем* или *сделать информацию доступной для тех*?

Answer (score 2):

Розенталь в справочнике об управлении приводит варианты как равноправные.

[image: Розенталь Д.Э. Пунктуация и управление в русском языке: Справочники для работников печати. — М.: Книга, 1988. — С. 296. — ISBN 5-212-00086-6.]

Розенталь Д.Э. Пунктуация и управление в русском языке: Справочники для работников печати. — М.: Книга, 1988. — С. 296. — ISBN 5-212-00086-6.

Answer (score 1):

Чем ближе к концу предложения, тем лучше звучит "для", а с "тем" наоборот.
В связи с этим так:
*Не для всех учащихся это доступно.*
звучит хуже, чем так:
*Не всем учащимся это доступно.*
А так нормально:
*Это доступно не для всех учащихся.*